# How to display awarded ad in method OnAppearing() using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, admob

I want to display awarded ad when app is starting.

I load ads under `InitializeComponent();` with this code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Load Interestitial Ad
        CrossMTAdmob.Current.LoadInterstitial("ca-app-pub-9688730828394396/1781454910");
        //Load Rewarded Ad
        CrossMTAdmob.Current.LoadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-9688730828394396/9667490273"); 
    }
```

I have two buttons when users click on them different ads starting with this code:

```
private void ShowReward_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowRewardedVideo();
    }


    private void ShowInterstitial_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowInterstitial();
    }
```

I try to put `CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowInterstitial();` from one button in my `OnAppearing()` method but when I start application, the ad does not appear with this code:

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SetEvents();
        CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowInterstitial();
    }
```

Can I get some example how to display my ad when app is starting ?

Comment: this is Xamarin Forms, not Xamarin iOS

Comment: Ok, Thanks can you give me correct answer, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the plugin you are using.
You should check if the ads is actually loaded before trying to show it.
You can use
IsInterstitialLoaded()
And
IsRewardedVideoLoaded().

If these methods return true, then you can show the ads.
If the result is always false then you have to understand why they are not loaded, you can see in the output windows if you receive some error messages.
Most of the time the reason is a wrong Id.

Comment: Marco Troncone when the app starts in the constructor CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowInterstitial(); for the first time come true and when I click the button to display the ad He work. But when I put CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowInterstitial(); In the OnAppearing() method, CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowInterstitial(); again come true but the ad cannot display.